# TableLayout Trouble

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I am making 10x10 board of buttons, however, whenever I run my program, it is just 1 column with buttons extending to the bottom until I can't see them anymore. Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(32, 32);
    final TableLayout container = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout5);

    Button btn[][] = new Button[10][10];

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
             btn [i][j] = new Button(this);


             container.addView(btn[i][j],i,lp);

        }

    }

}
```

and my XML code

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5">



    <Button
    android:id="@+id/newgamebutton"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/newgame" />

  <TableLayout
      android:id="@+id/tableLayout5"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="400dp"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/newgamebutton"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

  </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm wondering why the buttons are extending all the way to the bottom and disappearing, I don't know if it has something to do with my layout height or not. I intend it to look like a 10x10 board

Comment: try putting tablelayout inside a scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you need a 10x10 board of buttons you need to create TableRows as well. Currently you have none. Please read the TableLayout documentation to understand how it works.

Secondly if you do need to programmatically set layout parameters on a Table you have to use TableRow.LayoutParams, and not ViewGroup.LayoutParams.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(32, 32);
```

I used this instead:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(32, 32);
```